# Duplicate rows while joining multiple tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch records from 7 different tables having user_id as foreign key in each table . I use Left Join to join multiple tables to fetch desire columns from different tables . But query returns duplicate rows.

Here is my query

```
SELECT users.User_No
      ,users.User_Name
      ,users.User_Appointment
      ,request_co.*
      ,personal_service.*
      ,personal_physical.Personal_Country_Of_Birth
      ,personal_physical.Personal_City_Of_Birth
      ,personal_medical.*
      ,personal_religion.*
      ,personal_family.Personal_Family_Caste
      ,personal_family.Personal_Family_Marital_Status
  FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN request_co 
      ON users.User_No = request_co.forwarded_user_id 
    LEFT JOIN personal_service 
      ON users.User_No = personal_service.User_Id 
    LEFT JOIN personal_physical 
      ON users.User_No = personal_physical.User_Id 
    LEFT JOIN personal_medical 
      ON users.User_No = personal_medical.User_Id
    LEFT JOIN personal_religion 
      ON users.User_No = personal_religion.User_Id
    LEFT JOIN personal_family 
      ON users.User_No = personal_family.User_Id
  WHERE request_co.status = 'APPROVED'  
  ORDER BY request_co.date DESC
```

When I run above query it returns 6064866 duplicate rows but my desire output is only 6 rows
Please help me to avoid duplicate rows and sort the issue

Regards

Comment: I can't think of any way for SQL's `LEFT INNER JOIN` to generate a result with more entries than the initial table. Can you clarify what you mean by 'duplicate rows' as well as specify the count of entries in `users` ?

Comment: I think as Alceste. What is `duplicate` for you ? Record with distinct `USER_NO` ! Can you give us 2 or 3 records that, for you, are duplicated and explain why ? Can you add this information in your question ?